# Install Ethereum Wallet and Mist on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wallets, mist, ubuntu

Hi I am new in Blockchain. I try to install Ethereum Wallet and Mist on Ubuntu 18.04 and I got error as below:

```
Selecting previously unselected package ethereumwallet:i386.
(Reading database ... 233996 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Ethereum-Wallet-linux32-0-11-1.deb ...
Unpacking ethereumwallet:i386 (0.11.1-2616) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ethereumwallet:i386:
 ethereumwallet:i386 depends on gconf2.
 ethereumwallet:i386 depends on libnotify4.
 ethereumwallet:i386 depends on libappindicator1.
 ethereumwallet:i386 depends on libxtst6.
 ethereumwallet:i386 depends on libnss3.
 ethereumwallet:i386 depends on libxss1.

dpkg: error processing package ethereumwallet:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ethereumwallet:i386
```

Please help:)

Comment: Hi there. What command did you run? Are there any further error logs that give more details about the errors?

Comment: I use command: sudo dpkg -i Ethereum-Wallet-linux32-0-11-1.deb

Answer (score 0):

Try the Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-11-1.zip for Ubuntu 18
I am using it on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.